# Converting list output in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a function that works as follows to read a .csv file and store it in an array.

```
def read_csv(self, filename, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"'):
    reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter = delimiter, quotechar = quotechar)
    # read first line and extract its data 
    self.column_headings = np.array(next(reader))
    # read subsequent lines
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)
    self.data = np.array(rows)
    self.m, self.n = self.data.shape
```

I'm simply trying to read a .tsv file so that it will return in the same form. I have this so far :

```
traindata = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2]
```

However, when I try to call :

```
m, n = traindata.data.shape

# Display
print m, n, traindata.column_headings
```

I get the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1f877ccb37b5> in <module>()
----> 1 m, n = traindata.data.shape

AttributeError: 'buffer' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: if you're reading a .tsv file (ie. a tab separated value file) should the delimiter not be '\t'?

Comment: @superjump The read_csv function is just for reading csv files, I'd like the tsv I am reading to be in the same format but cannot seem to call the 
print m, n, traindata.column_headings function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly create a `list` of `traindata`:

```
traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2])
          # ^ here
```

If you want to use it as a `numpy.array`, remove the `list()` call:

```
traindata = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2]
```

Secondly, you want the `shape` of the `array`, not its `data`:

```
m, n = traindata.shape
```

Comment: Oh. God. I need a coffee. Sorry, didn't mean to spam like this, you know sometimes how your eyes get crossed from coding too long?! Sorry again, thank you :)

Comment: You have changed the question, meaning my answer is no longer correct. However, I have added an answer to your second problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It is unfortunately now returning the error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e8668026004b> in <module>()
----> 1 m, n = traindata.shape

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

however. Would you please be able to offer some guidance here?

Comment: It appears that your `traindata` is one-dimensional, so `shape` is a 1-tuple and can't be unpacked to two values.

Comment: This confuses me, as my traindata isn't one-dimensional. An extract of it I have uploaded here : http://pastebin.com/w9tc7tHZ and the full amount can be downloaded from http://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/data (train.tsv file). I don't understand why it should produce this error message, unless perhaps I am handling quotation marks incorrectly? Apologies for the nuisance here, but any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Well have you tried just printing out `traindata.shape`? The raw data may not appear to be one-dimensional, but the error message implies `shape` is a 1-tuple, so you may not be correctly processing the data into your `array`.

Comment: I have created a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666066/data-being-read-as-one-dimensional-but-is-not-valueerror-need-more-than-1-va since we have moved on a bit from here. I have tried to print traindata.shape and this return 7,395 (the number of rows), which is correct, but why can I not get the number of columns? Thanks a lot for all your help.