# Data being read as one dimensional but is not - "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am reading the following data :

[Link - train.tsv file](http://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/data) ------
[(An extract uploaded here)](http://pastebin.com/w9tc7tHZ)

using the following method :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as p
print "loading data.."
traindata = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2]
column_headings = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,-1]

print "complete..."
```

When I try to run the following :

```
m,n  = traindata.shape
```

I get the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-570e485a0a88> in <module>()
----> 1 m,n  = traindata.shape

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I wish to be able to run :

print m, n, column_headings

which, in my mind, should return something like :

> 7395, 27, "url"   "urlid" "boilerplate"   "alchemy_category"
>   "alchemy_category_score"        "avglinksize"   "commonlinkratio_1"
>   "commonlinkratio_2"     "commonlinkratio_3"     "commonlinkratio_4"
>   "compression_ratio"     "embed_ratio"   "framebased"
>   "frameTagRatio" "hasDomainLink" "html_ratio"    "image_ratio"
>   "is_news"       "lengthyLinkDomain"     "linkwordscore"
>   "news_front_page"       "non_markup_alphanum_characters"
>   "numberOfLinks" "numwords_in_url"       "parametrizedLinkRatio"
>   "spelling_errors_ratio" "label"

(7,395 being the total number of rows, and 27 being the total number of columns).

and ultimately I would like to be able to get each columns values by a single command similar to :

```
url_values = traindata.function('url')
```

However I know from investigating this that the column_headers are printing incorrectly and for some reason I am only being returned one dimension. How can I also get each columns values in this way?

What have I done wrong? How can I achieve the desired output?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using `[:,2]` if you don't want to extract a particular column?  Do you have to postprocess that column somehow?  Why are you setting `column_headings` to the data in the rightmost column? Is that where they are?

Comment: I think your indexing is backwards, at least for the headings. You index into rows first then columns. So you should have "column_headings = ...[0] would be just the heading.

Answer (score 1):

You transformed your data for `traindata` into a one-dimensional array by using `[:,2]`, which is why `traindata.shape()` only returns one value. This causes your error

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Hence you can omit that part and adjust your code as follows for your desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as p
print("loading data..")

traindata = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))#[:,2]
column_headings = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv', header=None))[0]

print("complete...")

m,n  = traindata.shape

print(m, n, column_headings)
```

**Output:**

```
6 27 ['url' 'urlid' 'boilerplate' 'alchemy_category' 'alchemy_category_score'
 'avglinksize' 'commonlinkratio_1' 'commonlinkratio_2' 'commonlinkratio_3'
 'commonlinkratio_4' 'compression_ratio' 'embed_ratio' 'framebased'
 'frameTagRatio' 'hasDomainLink' 'html_ratio' 'image_ratio' 'is_news'
 'lengthyLinkDomain' 'linkwordscore' 'news_front_page'
 'non_markup_alphanum_characters' 'numberOfLinks' 'numwords_in_url'
 'parametrizedLinkRatio' 'spelling_errors_ratio' 'label']
```